# Twitter Bootstrap navbar not working in PLAY framework

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, playframework

I have a main.scala.html which has header,navbar and footbar as follows-

```
    @(title: String)(content: Html)

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
            <ul  class="nav nav-justified" id="myTab">

              <li><a href="@routes.Application.apps()" data-toggle="tab">@Messages("views.main.apps")</a></li>
            <li ><a href="#" data-toggle="tab">@Messages("views.main.activity")</a></li>
            <li><a href="@routes.Application.devices()" data-toggle="tab">@Messages("views.main.devices")</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-toggle="tab">@Messages("views.main.account")</a></li>
            <li id="logout" data-toggle="tab"><a href="#">@Messages("views.main.logout")</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div id="showData">
            @content
            </div>
    </div>
</head>
<body>
    </body>
    </html>
```

The page content should be displayed as in the  tags.
However on clicking the tabs the page contents are not getting displayed.

Note the page contents were getting displayed earlier on clicking on the tabs but after adding data-toggle="tab" to the list elements it stopped displaying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your html code:

```
...
<head>
    <ul  class="nav nav-justified" id="myTab">
```

There is a end head and start div tag missing.

Answer (score 0):

Preview source code generated by Play in the browser and use built-in browser inspector for HTML error (also you can just try to validate it with [W3C Validator](http://validator.w3.org/)

If your view looks exactly as you showed as - it **can not** produce valid HTML document

Comment: I was just trying to pull up a snippet from my existing code base which is completely in HTML.Sorry I missed the </head> tag